# Filling hidden input field from select menu using Js

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am using this function:

```
function selectionchange() {
  var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('txt').value = str;
}
```

to fill the hidden field when changing options:

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="selectionchange();">
    <option value="1">Sun</option>
    <option value="2">Moon</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="txt" value="">
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: It works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vog3xq7n/

Comment: works here https://jsfiddle.net/4t3dt4n4/ Check your console for other errors

Comment: The code works for me too... What is not working as expected for you? Are you not receiving the "txt" value after sending the form? Are you not seeing the "txt" value in the DOM when you inspect the element?...

Comment: `but it does not work` - What are you expecting?

Comment: Yes @PetrHejda I do not see the value in the source code, but it is there when inspecting the DOM.

Comment: When you view the source code in your browser, it shows it only in state how it was loaded. Usually, browsers' source code viewers don't apply DOM changes after the DOM load into the source code. You can use some web developer extensions to your browser to be able to see source code changes after the DOM load... Also, when you send the form as it is now, you'll be able to work with the data that your JS correctly put into the "txt" input field.

Comment: Now all good, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag of `< /script>` looks bad. Not sure if it is caused by editing. But I have tested the code after changing `< /script>` to `</script>` and it worked fine.